# show error message when model.item is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am displaying two partial views in a View. The partial views are displayed well. 
But if the model value is null, how to show error message in my Partial View.
Below is my code :

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult MyAccount(string email)
        {
            OrderModel objorder = new OrderModel();
            var OrderDetails = objorder.GetOrderInfo(email);
            if(OrderDetails == null)
            {
               // ViewBag.Message = "You have not placed any orders.";
                ModelState.AddModelError("NoOrders", "You have not placed any orders.");
                return View();
            }
            CustomerModel objcustomer = new CustomerModel();
            var CustomerDetails =  objcustomer.GetCustomerInfo(email);            
            return View(Tuple.Create(OrderDetails, CustomerDetails));
        }
```

View

```
@model Tuple<IList<MvcApplication1.Models.OrderModel>, IList<MvcApplication1.Models.CustomerModel>>

@Html.Partial("MyOrders")<br/>
@Html.Partial("AccountInfo")
```

Partial View 1
@model Tuple, IList>

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {   
        if (Model.Item1 != null) // Null reference unhandled by user code 
        {
            <div>
              @foreach(var item in Model.Item1)
              {
               @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.OrderID) 
              }
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
           <p>@Html.ValidationMessage("NoOrders", new { @class = "msg" })</p>
        }
    }
```

I have passed the validation message for null values to handle in Partial View1.
But I am getting object reference not set and null reference unhandled message.
What is the mistake in my code.? Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Model` is `null`.

This:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("NoOrders", "You have not placed any orders.");
return View();
```

Creates a `null` model in your view. So this:

```
if (Model.Item1 != null)
// ^^^^^^ THIS IS NULL!
```

..won't work.

You need:

```
if (Model != null)
```

Although I must say.. your application logic/flow makes me sad. There are various ways to accomplish this in MVC.. passing a `null` model is probably one of the uglier ways.

Comment: Yes. it makes the entire model of the tuple as null.